# What scriptures describe night being caused by mount Meru?

Tags: puranas, temple, india

Lalla's Shishyavriddhida Tantra is a Hindu astronomical work dating to the 8th century.  In [this chapter](http://gdurl.com/JaoM) of the Shishyavriddhida Tantra, Lalla attempts to refute various astronomical theories he regards as false.  Most of the theories he tries to refute are ones found in Hindu scripture: the theory that eclipses are caused by Rahu and Ketu, the theory that the Earth is supported by the serpent Adiseshan, the theory that the Moon is farther than the Sun, the theory that the Earth moves, etc.  But there's one theory he tries to refute that I'm not familiar with:

> **Again, some say that the night is caused by the darkness due to the mountain Meru.**...  If the night of the men in this world is caused by the Meru covering the Sun, tell me how the night of the gods, (who live on the Meru) and feed on nectar, is caused.  (Therefore the statement) is irrational.  When the Sun goes to the southern part (of the ecliptic beginning with) Libra, it is always night for the dwellers of Meru.  When it moves along the north (of the ecliptic beginning with) Aries, (it is continuous night) for the demons.  When the Sun is hidden by part of the earth, it is night for the men also.  Just as the shadow of a tree is longer when it is directly opposite to the Sun than at other times, so is the part of the shadow of the earth (directly) opposite to the Sun.

So Lalla concludes that night is caused not by the shadow of mount Meru, but rather by the shadow of the Earth, which incidentally is the view of modern science.  But my question is, what scriptures describe night being caused by the shadow of mount Meru?

I have come across passages in the Puranas which describe the Sun (and other planets) circling mount Meru.  But does anyone know if any scriptures say that night is caused by Meru blocking the Sun?